# How to avoid writing to a color attachment in the fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

Let's say I have a framebuffer with 2 color attachments. And I specify the draw buffers like:

```
GLenum drawBufs[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
glDrawBuffers(2, drawBufs);
```

In most of my shaders I will declare the two outputs:

```c
layout (location = 0) out vec4 o_color0;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 o_color1;
```

But there are some special cases where I don't what to write to `o_color1`.
I have seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545966/opengl-3-0-framebuffer-outputting-to-attachments-without-me-specifying) that, even if you don't write to one of the outputs, OpenGL will write undefined values.

However, even if I don't declare the output in the shader

```c
layout (location = 0) out vec4 o_color0;
//layout (location = 1) out vec4 o_color1;
```

it looks like OpenGL is still writing stuff to the second attachment.

In the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers) I have seen mentioned that if you don't specify a location.

```c
layout (location = 0) out vec4 o_color0;
out vec4 o_color1;
```

OpenGL will assign one arbitrarilly, but I don't know what happens when you dont declare the output.

Also in the wiki, in the context of outputs automatic assignment, says the following:

> Automatic assignment for fragment shader outputs makes even less sense than for vertex shader inputs. The color numbers (as explained below) refer to a draw buffer as defined by glDrawBuffers. You are very likely to use the same Framebuffer for many different programs (while you will probably frequently change VAOs); changing glDrawBuffers state, and re-validating the FBO every time, is probably not a good idea.

When it says it's not a good idea to call `glDrawBuffers`, I guess it's because it's expensive? What would be the best way to achive what I need? The options mentioned in the linked question don't sound cheap either.

Comment: It says "This question already has an answer here" but that's the exact same question I explicitly linked, and it's not answering my question :(